# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) ...... Check the render method of `App`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compiler-errors

[LINK TO PHOTO OF FILE TREE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMWk5.png)

[PHOTO OF AUTH0 APP AFTER CODE FIXES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZwpP.png)

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

- Why are I getting this error?

`index.js`

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { makeMainRoutes } from './routes';

const routes = makeMainRoutes();

ReactDOM.render(
  routes,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`routes.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import Home from './Home/Home';
import Callback from './Callback/Callback';
import Auth from './Auth/Auth';
import history from './history';

const auth = new Auth();

const handleAuthentication = (nextState, replace) => {
  if (/access_token|id_token|error/.test(nextState.location.hash)) {
    auth.handleAuthentication();
  }
}

export const makeMainRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={history} component={App}>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" render={(props) => <App auth={auth} {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/home" render={(props) => <Home auth={auth} {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/callback" render={(props) => {
          handleAuthentication(props);
          return <Callback {...props} /> 
        }}/>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

`App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  goTo(route) {
    this.props.history.replace(`/${route}`)
  }

  login() {
    this.props.auth.login();
  }

  logout() {
    this.props.auth.logout();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { renewSession } = this.props.auth;

    if (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') === 'true') {
      renewSession();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth;

    return (
      <div>
        {/* <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/auth0-js/build/auth0.js"></script> */}
        {/* <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/auth0/9.10/auth0.min.js"></script> */}

        <Navbar fluid>
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <a href="#">Auth0 - React</a>
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Button
              bsStyle="primary"
              className="btn-margin"
              onClick={this.goTo.bind(this, 'home')}
            >
              Home
            </Button>
            {
              !isAuthenticated() && (
                  <Button
                    id="qsLoginBtn"
                    bsStyle="primary"
                    className="btn-margin"
                    onClick={this.login.bind(this)}
                  >
                    Log In
                  </Button>
                )
            }
            {
              isAuthenticated() && (
                  <Button
                    id="qsLogoutBtn"
                    bsStyle="primary"
                    className="btn-margin"
                    onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}
                  >
                    Log Out
                  </Button>
                )
            }
          </Navbar.Header>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Everything seems fine from a glance. Is that the correct import & directory for your App component? The others are `folder/component`?

Comment: @TomFinney I will put a screenshot of my file tree above^

Comment: `Navbar.Header` is probably undefined. Check https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/

Comment: @nickwgiannini did this just start happening out of the blue after it was working previously? can you post your package.json as well? you might be using a version of react bootstrap that doesn't have some of the components you're using?

Comment: @UjinT34 @TomFinney I took `Navbar.Header` out and I am not getting that error anymore.  By now my Auth0 implementation is not registering.  I followed along exactly how their website told me to do it.

Comment: @UjinT34 also, where should I put my script tags for the Auth0 application?  I dont have an index.html or any HTML files for that matter in my react application.  I don't know where to put them using jsx

Answer (score 0):

`undefined && whatever` resolves to `undefined`. Check the value returned by `this.props.auth.isAuthenticated()`. It should be boolean. You can use `!!` to fix the issue:

```
        {
          !!isAuthenticated() && (
              <Button
                id="qsLogoutBtn"
                bsStyle="primary"
                className="btn-margin"
                onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}
              >
                Log Out
              </Button>
            )
        }
```

But since you have to alternatives for this conditional it is better just to use this code:

```
        {
          isAuthenticated() ? (
              <Button
                id="qsLogoutBtn"
                bsStyle="primary"
                className="btn-margin"
                onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}
              >
                Log Out
              </Button>
            ) : (
              <Button
                id="qsLoginBtn"
                bsStyle="primary"
                className="btn-margin"
                onClick={this.login.bind(this)}
              >
                Log In
              </Button>
            )
        }
```

Comment: I implemented these changes, but I am still seeing the same error

Comment: Don't think that's the issue because you can usually just do `{undefined}` in a component body and it's fine. Check out: https://codesandbox.io/s/r4r059n6mm?fontsize=14